# Export Sqlite database from Windows Store App

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, filepicker

I've got a Sqlite database which I populate inside a Windows Store app. Now I'd like to have said database availiable when reinstalling the app, therefore I have to add it to my project as a file, if I'm right.

Now I'm trying to export the database file using the PickSaveFileAsync()-Method. Unfortunately I don't really know how to go about this once I've got the file. Here's what I've got so far:

```
    private async void exportDB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile database = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Hashes.db");
        var picker = new FileSavePicker();
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Database File", new string[] { ".db" });
        picker.CommitButtonText = "Save DB";
        picker.SuggestedFileName = "Database";
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // What to do here?
        }
    }
```

Comment: users should not have to export and therefore import app database between updates or re-installations don't you think? Do you have other user friendly option?

Comment: There will be an end-user and an admin version for this app, the database export will be only availiable for the latter one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Looking at the code it seems that you want to copy your database file to a user defined location. To do this just add the following code inside your `if` block:

```
using (var srcStream = await database.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    using (var destStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await srcStream.CopyToAsync(destStream);
    }
}
```

Reading the introductory text it seems you're trying to include the file with your application. In this case you should indeed add it as `Content` to your project. You can then access it from code as follows:

```
var dbFile = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"db\Hashes.db");
```

In case you didn't know, you can find the files in `LocalFolder` in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PackageName\LocalState
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was indeed exactely what I was looking for.
I also didn't know that I can find the database-file in the app folder, that will also come in handy!