# how to copy file from my app Using FileSavePicker UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want copy file in my app to a folder with FileSavePicker. My Code:

```
var fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
fileSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

var filedb = new[] { ".db" };
fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("DB", filedb);
fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = "BACKUPDB" + System.DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + System.DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + System.DateTime.Now.Year;

//var pathDB = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "file.db");

try
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("file.db");
    StorageFile localfile = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    fileSavePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = file;

    if (file != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("file Exists!!"); 
        var fileToSave = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        ....
```

but my saved file has size 0.

I found how to save text files but my file not is text.

Comment: You haven't included the code which does the actual file copy.

Comment: this is a question I do not know. I tried the way it is in the code and the file saved with zero size

Comment: thx for attention.i found it solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305758/export-sqlite-database-from-windows-store-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CopyAndReplaceAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738482.aspx) method to copy your local file to the chosen file.

```
var fileSavePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
fileSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

var filedb = new[] { ".db" };
fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("DB", filedb);
fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = "BACKUPDB" + System.DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + System.DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + System.DateTime.Now.Year;

//var pathDB = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "file.db");

try
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("file.db");
    StorageFile localfile = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("file Exists!!");
        await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(localfile);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, i did too using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305758/export-sqlite-database-from-windows-store-app/15309471#15309471
but the your is better because more faster.

Now, i will procedure reverse with FileOpenPicker()